# Open ports with no associated PIDs

Tags: networking, process, netstat

I have some open ports on my laptop but `netstat` is not reporting which PID/Program is associated with them:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8307          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13819           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32107/skype         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:902             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::902                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

How can I figure out which process has these open? In particular `443`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> ```
> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
>  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> ```

Try running netstat using sudo, i.e. `sudo netstat ...`